# What is the limit $( 1 + 1/\tan(n) )^{\tan(n)}$

Tags: limits, recreational-mathematics

What is the result of 
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan(n)}\right)^{\tan(n)}$ = ?

The limit does not exist as stated by Adam Rubinson.

Looks like the requested answer is **e** but then the question is wrong. 
What is the correct question to give the answer **e**?

Did answered correctly. But I think this is some kind of typographical error. 
This question appeared on a high school test and the intended question should have a small error.
What is the correct question to give the answer **e** changing only one value?

Comment: What makes you think that this limit exists?

Comment: Even if we set the domain as R \ {(1/2)n*pi}, the "limit" is not really a limit. It "Oscillates" by "starting" at 1/e, spending a fair amount of it's time near 1, then buzzing off to e. Rinse and repeat this process. So the limit does not exist.

Comment: Joe Oliver - The correct question would then be "What is limsup...?"

Comment: "Did answered correctly" Two characters disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lim_{n\to\color{red}{\pi/2}}\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan(n)}\right)^{\tan(n)} = e$$

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct question to give the answer $\mathrm e$?

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\tan(1/n)\right)^{1/\tan(1/n)} =\ ?
$$

Comment: This is slightly more likely to be the "correct question" then my proposed question, whatever is meant by "correct question".